# Is someone who has the power to manifest things on the internet able to solve all of the worlds problems?

Tags: internet, power

Background: 2030, United States. Information freedom access Act was passed in 2029, granting complete access to the internet for all citizens. Technology is mildly more advanced (meaning better versions of todays technology, like faster computers, better healthcare, more powerful machines, more eco friendly cars, etc.) without scifi tech like hovercars and time machines, starships and the like.

How the power works: I have a system in my world where someone who possesses the "master manifest" can use anything on the internet in real life. For example, since there are pictures of unicorns on the internet, someone who possesses the "master manifest" would be able to create unicorns.  This has several other implications. Since there are articles about food on the internet, the Master Manifest would be able to make food. Couple that with the Wikipedia article about infinity, and the Master Manifest can solve the worlds hunger crisis. Is the Master Manifest hunted by shady corporations who make their money off of people's hunger? Just use the game on the internet of Call of Duty aimbot with sniper to snipe off the agents sent after the Master Manifest. Aliens invading? Just use the movie "War of the Worlds" where the aliens just fall over and die. Feeling sad? Just manifest all of the countless websites about depression, and maybe some articles about medications.

The goal: The goal I am trying to accomplish is to (in-universe) solve the worlds problems, like cancer and hunger and war and whatnot. I want to know if it is possible to do so in my world, based on the mechanics of the Master Manifest given.

Constraints: Since I am aware from the Help Center that I need to limit my query to a finite and sharply defined set of rules, I will define "the world's problems" as thus;
War/violence, mental health issues, crime, and pain/human frailty.

The question: Can these 4 issues be solved with the Master Manifest as described?

Comment: What do you consider as "internet"? Does it include everything accessible online including netflix and Stadia streaming services, or only web pages (the one you're currently looking at, with your web browser)? I'm also unsure if I fully grasp the extent of the power, how far can you dodgestep the data's original intent? For instance if it's a wikipedia page on a movie, can you make the movie's story true, can you change the story with another web page?

Comment: @Pelinore I meant that anything on the net, you can make real. Like if you see pic of a cupcake online, you can actually make the cupcake.

Comment: @Tortliena Everything accessible online. You can change the story with another webpage, as long as the webpage is talking about the movie.

Comment: Internet includes anything on a computer network. So servers, streaming, websites, videos, movies, anything you can access from a computer.

Comment: Ah, and yes, are there costs to the manifest process? As it is stated, I feel like the answer is quite trivial as your power -as I understand it- is essentially godlike, especially when you do the right actions...

Comment: There isn't a cost, but you are limited by what is on the internet. You also have to _know_ it is on the internet (i.e. if you've never seen nyan cat, you can't make nyan cat).

Comment: @BarryHenderson ah! I see, you mean manifest as in 'magically' materialise rather than simply meaning someone with control over what appears anywhere on the internet  goes a bit against the without sci fi tech bit unless your going for actual magic doesn't it? .. gimme a minute to read the rest of it.

Comment: @BarryHenderson there are various religious texts available on the internet. Could you manifest a god? Can you manifest a dead person? Would they know everything they knew in life? Can you manifest a planet? Can you manifest a species of humans who don't have a tendency to sacrifice their futures for short term gains, etc?

Comment: It's actual magic. It is the Master Manifest. Basically, the internet has a "lie of its own" and it has a mechanism by which the digital can become actual. However, this is specific to the internet. However, this can be avoided by the person who possesses the Master Manifest, who could manifest scifi elements if they chose to.

Comment: @StarfishPrime yes, but you cannot make them have knowledge/personality.

Comment: Unless you have the knowledge/personality on the Internet described

Comment: @BarryHenderson so their minds though fully formed biologically would essentially be a blank slate? .. adult simulacra would likely be unable to form the developmental changes needed to learn to talk and maybe even walk if you're strictly following the known science and research while one of a baby might develop normally as it grew after being 'manifested' .. not that that is vitally important to you question  just a random observation.

Comment: @Pelinore they would, if you didn't manifest the part of the internet that says that all psychology comes from the physical brain. If you manifested the part that says that souls exist, you could give the person a soul. But if you didn't manifest the part that says that the soul was the mind, then the soul still wouldn't make a person...

Comment: Well then, what you seem to be describing is ritual magic that can be manipulated by adding entries to the internet? adding the entries or finding and reading extant ones would fill the ritual element of casting the spell, what's called a 'bunk' in Changeling .. what needs to be known is the cost in materials and/or energy (if any) of casting your spells, otherwise it appears to simply be a 'the will and the word' scenario with no limits on potential results with which you can do literally anything.

Comment: @Pelinore since this internet based capability seems to be way too much (based on the answers and comments) what I could maybe do is have the energy equivalent to the amount of data is being manifested. For example, with 2 GB of stuff you want to make, you need maybe a car battery worth of electricity.

Answer (score 11):

## Omnipotence is a commonly discussed internet topic, so yes.

Religion and gods and omnipotence is a very commonly discussed issue on the internet. If you can manifest concepts you can manifest omnipotence and omniscience, and can do whatever you so wish.

Comment: Huh. I didn't think of that. Well, in that case, the Master Manifest could manifest God with a capital G, so then the Master Manifest would be able to solve literally _every_ problem. But the Master Manifest could also take away the God power, because their are plenty of websites saying that God doesn't exist. So it wouldn't be true omnipotence, because the Internet also includes atheist statements.

Comment: The "God" can only know what we humans know (or rather, what knowledge we've put on the internet, as per the rules of this fantasy). Wouldn't be a very useful God.

Comment: It may know *of* omniscience, but unless it also knows how to reach it (unless *we* know how to reach it), it can't have it.

Comment: Even with omnipotence, as it is discussed on internet and and it fiction, it is extremely difficult (and probably impossible) to solve "all problems" in the world. We can make real a fiction in which, ostensibly, "all problems are solved" - but looking closer, it's not the case.

Comment: @Alexander Nepene Nep is saying that since things on the internet can become real, and omnipotence is on the internet, the Master Manifest can make omnipotence real.

Comment: But you're right, I didn't intend for this power to be so strong. But that is why I get other people's input. To see things I didn't see before.

Comment: @Barry Henderson Thank you. I stand corrected then.

Comment: There are ample internet statements saying people control gods, or that they are gods, so you can manifest a capital G god and control them, and delete them at will.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, it's trivially easy

<sup>*This falls a bit as a frame-challenge, in that I think you missed a critical flaw (or more like strength) of your power.*</sup>

You're telling that anything can be made from content on the internet. Then to reach your goal you don't even need any existing content on the internet; You just need to be able to write anywhere on the web.

Here are the two steps to victory :

1. Write on your blog, as a comment or anywhere you wish that "you are omnipotent and omniscient", manifest it.
2. Since you've become omnipotent, you can alter the rules of the world<sup>1</sup>.

Everything else then falls on universe rules alteration, like if you are a god; Since you've become omnipotent, you can make anything, even things which would be theorically or logically impossible in our world as we know it. This of course includes the world problems you describe :).

---

<sup>1 : A bit like you, the worldbuilder have upon the world you're making, actually.</sup>

Comment: This is a really good point. I didn't think of that at all. This complicates things with the Master Manifest, since it makes it so that people can just Manifest anything that's not on the Internet by putting it on the Internet.

Comment: @BarryHenderson It's even worse, because as soon as you become omnipotent you can erase the manifest or internet altogether preventing anyone else from doing anything. Well, unless you tell that the manifest's omnipotence is always stronger than your omnipotence x).

Comment: Whoa. That is truly a game breaker. Although since the site https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GameBreaker exists and it has examples, I suppose it's really unavoidable.

Comment: I just had a thought. Wouldn't this question be part of the Internet now : O

Answer (score 5):

## Just find the right site

Adding to the other two answers, if you want to

- avoid giving yourself additional powers
- Adding something to the internet that isn’t already there

All you need is Google. A quick Google search found me [this site](https://iqdoodle.com/resourcefulness/) which conveniently contains the sentence

> All the world’s problems have been solved and we can live out the rest of our lives in perfect bliss and harmony.

In context, it’s a little more problematic, but that’s true of everything on the internet.

Just manifest that sentence and you’re good to go.

---

Edit: OP expressed potential concern about that site being taken down, so I've made an even [better backup option](https://codepen.io/danjruss/full/OJEpvWr).

[image]

Comment: And if it's not there, write it yourself. It's surely safer than my sentence; Who knows what an omnipotent being can unwillingly do ^^.

Comment: This site in my world would definitely literally solve all the worlds problems. I can't believe there was actually a site that said "all the world's problems have been solved." The internet is really titanic I guess. Not to mention that now if that site goes bust, then the sentence is not on the internet here...

Comment: @BarryHenderson Let me know if the updated answer relieves your concerns about the first site 'going bust'.

Comment: @DanielB yes, it does. I like the "problem solving button." Did you just make that?

Comment: @BarryHenderson I even named it The Barry Henderson Problem Solver for you!

Answer (score 4):

**The answer is a self-fullfilling "yes".**

I just stated that it's possible to use this power to solve all the world's problems, and did so on the internet. Therefore, it *actually is* possible to use this power to solve all the world's problems, simply because someone said it was on the internet.

Comment: Yep, it's a 'game breaking' power, to not be it would need some limitations set around it that it doesn't as currently written appear to have, only being able to 'manifest' physical objects might be a start but without some associated cost in materials probably not enough in itself to make every other character a pointless accessory in most stories .. not many writers can pull off an interesting story with a main character able to wield a power like this  every situation or problem devolves down to 'and he fixed it with his magic, because he can' not a lot of suspense or interest in that.

Comment: @Pelinore Not only the MC can use the power. It is just whoever has the Master Manifest. So anyone could use it, and they could transfer it to others if they so chose.

Comment: @BarryHenderson Yup, but as others have pointed out once someone has it they can just alter reality to prevent anyone else ever getting it and invest it's power in themselves in perpetuity .. once it's passed to more than one person it then becomes immersion breaking that no one who has it would think of that, because it makes the characters seem unreasonably dim  but that might just be me 

Comment: @Pelinore that makes sense. It could lead to a kind of dictator scenario; they get "elected" and then abolish all elections : )

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on the inteligence behind the power**

You didn't tell us how this power came to be. Or how it does manifest. Lets take for example a gun from a sci-fi game (lets take Mass effect as an example). If someone were to create it, what would be gun's power? Same as in the game? That is, it would take a few shots to put down someone? Or it would be like it was implied to be in (fictional) universe? So one shot should be enough to destroy a modern tank. And would it depend on the user, or the power itself?

Why would this matter? Because of a monkey's paw scenario. If the implementation is up to power itself (or subconsciousness of a user), that power would be really dangerous. Because you know what is the simplest solution to issues of war, famine, powerty,...? Removal of humanity. Want to solve those problems without removal of humanity? BAM! Humans are now mindless drones.

So in that case this power couldn't be used to solve all the world's problems, as it would be really difficult to use properly and without unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not! There is no way to solve all the problems because people will always want different things and these things are very often in conflict with one another. Each time you solve a problem, you will create multiple new problems.

Just take the movie Bruce Almighty when he granted everyone's prayer, the world was in total chaos after that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

One of the biggest problems people have is people.  People will find a reason to fight and compete.

If you want to see a take on what happens if you try to solve all of the world's problems like that, look up Lathe of Heaven by Ursula K. Le Guin ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven))

Comment: True of course, but how does that make it an insoluble problem? you just get rid of the people [shrugs] ;) or you can change them with your omnipotent powers so they're different, & if a problem crops up with your new design of people just rinse and repeat until you get it right .. the powers described are those of a literal god of all creation after all.

Comment: @Pelinore, The cure is worse than the disease?  Changing people: constant iterative changes until you might as well have killed off all the people.

Comment:  in this instance, perhaps only if you're anyone other than the one administering the cure 